# How to set char '+' && '-' in Regex?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Textbox.

I want set allow special char in it.

For example i want insert one '+'|'-' at index 0  then multy number

+12 , -324

i set this code for number

```
  Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
```

How to set only one char '+' || '-' before it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want there  to be exactly one `+` or `-` at the end of the box, and nowhere else, then your input string has to *match* the following expression.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9]+[+-]$");
```

Again, your string has to *match* this to be *valid* -  it looks like, for your original expression, the string is *invalid* if it matches.

If you want a single `+` or `-` *anywhere* in the box, you could use the following:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[0-9]+[+-][0-9]+$"); //requires digits before/after sign
Regex r = new Regex("^[0-9]+[+-][0-9]*$"); //requires digits before sign
Regex r = new Regex("^[0-9]*[+-][0-9]+$"); //requires digits after sign
Regex r = new Regex("^[0-9]*[+-][0-9]*$"); //doesn't require digits
```

Comment: for example: +154 or -12 ... but when i use your code i can insert any char for example 'df+41f'

Comment: Which of _my two regular expressions_ are you using? Also, do you want a single +- but _anywhere_ in the text box?

Comment: Wait... Are you using your regular expression such that if it matches you _fail_ validation?

Comment: i use both, i want a single +- in index 0 in textbox.

Comment: @ar.gorgin - Your examples are 123+ and 514-. Neither of those has a + or - at index 0. Could you explain in detail what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than you think:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9+-]+$");
```

Just make sure the `-` is at the very end of the character class if you want it to be taken literally.

Edit: If you want to allow a single + or - at the beginning, and nowhere else, try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[+-][0-9]+$");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but i want insert only one + in textbox?

Comment: You want to *insert* a +, or you want to *allow* one? What exactly are the rules you're trying to implement?

Comment: i want insert one char '+' then multiply number...with your code i can insert many number and many char '+'

Comment: I use this code but don't work . when use this , i can insert any char to textbox.

Comment: You must not be implementing the regex correctly. This pattern is very specific about what it allows.